# About base URL using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have deployed my backend in heroku and i got my endpoints and was tested from postman.Now when i updated my heroku endpoint in .env file of react js but still it doesnt work.what may be the issue behind it?

This is my .env file: 
`REACT_APP_BASE_URL ='http://payroll-account.herokuapp.com/api`

This is my axios file and i am using .env file as following:
`const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8080/api'`

Now if i use as following in my axios file it works fine:
`const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || 'http://payroll-account.herokuapp.com/api'`

Comment: `const BASE_URL =process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL && process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8080/api' `

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `REACT_APP_BASE_URL = 'http://payroll-account.herokuapp.com/api`

You are adding a `'` at the beginning of `URL string`. Please have a look that what is the different?

Anyway, now update your .env file:

`REACT_APP_BASE_URL = http://payroll-account.herokuapp.com/api`

And use it where you want something like below:

`const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8080/api'`

Hopefully now will work :)

Comment: import axios from 'axios';


const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || 'https://localhost:8080/api'

const https = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    responseType: 'json'
})

Comment: Why you are using axios.create() ...? Try axios.get() or axios.post() Inside there use the base url...